# Why does the score increase faster the second time the user plays my game?

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML game, if you press the "play" button, the game will start and the score will increase by one every second. If you then press the back button and click the play button again, the score resets to 0 (what I want it to do) but for some reason it starts counting up *faster* than one a second.

Why does that happen?

The JS is below:

```
var pscore = 0;
var scoretimer;
var counter = 1;

// ...


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#playbutton").click(function() {
    showScreen("#game");
    moveEnemy();

    // Start score counter:
    countdown();
    startdifficulty();
  });

  $(".backtomenu").click(function() {
    showScreen("#splash");
    resetgame();
  });

function updatescore() {
  pscore++; // Idiom - Accumulation. Keeps adding points to the pscore.
  $("#score span").text(pscore);
}

function countdown() {
  scoretimer = setInterval(updatescore, 1000);
}

function resetscore() {
  pscore = 0;
}


function stoptimers() {
  clearInterval(difficultytimer);
  clearInterval(spawnTimer);
}

// Function that will determine whether a player is hitting an enemy and will use the reset function to show the player they decided

function processcollisions() {
  var i = 0;
  var e = $(".enemy");
  if (e.position().left <= $("#player").position().left) {
    console.log("Process Collisions is Working");
  }
}

function resetgame() {
  pscore = 0;
  difficulty = 5000;
  clearInterval(difficultytimer);
  clearInterval(spawnTimer);
  console.log("game reset");
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Aeee/pen/yXBbor?editors=0010 Here's the codepen link as well

Comment: Questions that do not provide a [Minimal, Verifiable example](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2201) are off topic, and quickly closed; this also looks like a massive code dump (without any effort to format it for readability), and you go on to ask *three* seperate questions, where we require *one* per post. Please read the [help] section, in regards to how to ask a good question, and use this site, in general.

Comment: You should read the [help]; it will teach you how to format code in your posts so it's legible. The other major issue I see is that you're asking three different questions; generally on StackExchange you should ask one question per post, including only the minimal amount of relevant code necessary to parse each question. You can edit your post using the "edit" link above. You can click the "edited by" link above to see how I changed your post: I removed all but the first question, made that the first thing a reader sees, provided a descriptive title, and only included apparently-relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

I am not terribly familiar with JavaScript, but it looks like you are probably ending up with two callbacks to `setInterval` that increase the score.

When you hit the play button, you call `countdown()`, which uses `setInterval` to register a callback to `updatescore()` periodically.

You don't clear that callback when you click on the back button; you call `resetgame()`, which clears two *other* timers, but not (apparently) the one you used to call `updatescore()`. So when you hit play again, you just start calling `updatescore()` *twice* every second.

You probably need to `clearInterval(scoretimer)` in `resetgame()`.